# My UIButton is starting in a random position instead of starting in the center and moving

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift3

In my code, I want the UIButton to start in the center of the screen then after I click on it, I want it to move to a random position on the screen. So I put the code for it to go to a random position after I click on it in, although the problem is that it is starting in a random position instead of starting in the center. Here is the code for my ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    btn.layer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.view.center.y)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func tapRandomBTN(_ sender: Any) {
    let buttonWidth = btn.frame.width
    let buttonHeight = btn.frame.height

    // Find the width and height of the enclosing view
    let viewWidth = btn.superview!.bounds.width
    let viewHeight = btn.superview!.bounds.height

    // Compute width and height of the area to contain the button's center
    let xwidth = viewWidth - buttonWidth
    let yheight = viewHeight - buttonHeight

    // Generate a random x and y offset
    let xoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(xwidth)))
    let yoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(yheight)))

    // Offset the button's center by the random offsets.
    btn.center.x = xoffset + buttonWidth / 2
    btn.center.y = yoffset + buttonHeight / 2

}
```

}

Comment: in `viewDidLoad` there is no layout information present, therefore everything related to frame, position, location, center, ... is not set / defined / random. Try `viewDidLayoutSubviews` e.g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @luk2302 points out in his comment, you can't rely on view frames being correct in viewDidLoad. You need to move that logic to viewDidLayoutSubviews.

However, note that if anything causes the system to invoke viewDidLayoutSubviews, your button will snap back to it's original position.

If you want it to stay in it's randomized position once it's moved there, you should add a "wasRandomized" boolean instance variable, and make the logic in viewDidLayoutSubviews only move the button to the center if you haven't randomized it already.

Also note that you should really be using layout constraints. Create a layout constraint for the x position and another one for y, and modify their constant values when you want to move the button. That way auto-layout won't move your button position out from under you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have the UIbutton in Storyboard. To make the UIButton start at cneter,set the layout constraints of the UIButton in storyboard as

1. Horizontally in container
2. Vertically in container
3. Constant width and Height

Also the code in viewDidLoad

```
btn.layer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.view.center.y)
```

is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You really should be using constraints. If you arent using them because you don't want to work within storyboards there is a way to set them programatically. It does require a little settup though

IMPORTANT: Apple doesn't want you to use this method, but I found this way helpful in understanding constraints and made the transition to using storyboards much easier. Here is a video guide if you're interested.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWSc0wHFTXM&t=6s

```
//example of programatic constraints (swift3):

button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: randomX).isActive = true
button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: randomY).isActive = true
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55.0).isActive = true
button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55.0).isActive = true
```